# Inherited Razor View - how to run an initializer method?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I've created an abstract class that inherits from WebPageView

```
public abstract class TemplateEngine<TModel> : WebViewPage<TModel> {
}
```

When my view renders, I execute some initializer code - for e.g.

```
@{
    Init();
}
```

I'd ideally like to avoid this and somehow execute it within the class, a method that Razor calls when it's about to render the view, so that all inherited view pages don't need me to write this line.

I tried overriding Execute() and it never gets called.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can override the `InitializePage` method.

```
public abstract class TemplateEngine<TModel> : WebViewPage<TModel> 
{
    protected override void InitializePage()
    {
    }
}
```